# Uniform Continuity ? How can you tell?

Tags: uniform-continuity

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+e^x}$.

Is f uniformly continuous?

In general, how can you recognize if a function is uniformly continuous?

[image]

Comment: One way is to show that $|f'|$ is bounded. (This gives a sufficient condition.)

Comment: In this case f'(x)=... I added it in the question above. It is not bounded right ? any other hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two conditions which will help you in most cases:

- If a function is Lipschitz-continuous, it is in particular uniformly continuous. As noted in the comments, this follows e.g. if $f$ is differentiable and $|f'|$ is bounded (and works in your case).
- If a function defined on a compact set is continuous, it is automatically uniformly continuous. This also implies that continuous periodic functions are uniformly continuous.

Edit: Your derivative is certainly bounded ;)

Comment: In [0,infinity) it is bounded. But what about (infinity,0] ? How can you bound the functions in this part ? :/

Comment: For example by noting that the function is even ;)

Comment: @Dragoslav $f$ is neither even nor odd. To bound in the negatives $x \in (-\infty, 0]$, observe that $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to - \infty$.

Comment: @ABlumenthal But $f'$ is even -- that's the point here ;)

Comment: @Dragoslav So it is. Pardon me...